# Magento2.3 - How to fix loop error in account dashboard?

Tags: magento2.3, phtml, sidebar, myaccount, collapsible

We have implemented our own design into the My Account dashboard. When we do our implementation, we have added some lines of code in the file collapsible.phtml. The issue now we are facing is that one of the div is looping and we aren't sure where the loop comes from.

You can see in the below screenshot the user name in the sidebar is appending:

[image]

[image]

Below is the code in collpasible phtml file:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
?>
<div class="title block-collapsible-nav-title user-avatar">
    <div class="user-header-image">
        <img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/myaccount.png'); ?>' alt="Demo">
    </div>
    <?php
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            echo $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
            // <span class="user-name user-text-base">Sivakumar</span>
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="block my-account-sidebar-head <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>">
    <div class="title <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>-title" data-mage-init='{"toggleAdvanced": {"toggleContainers": "#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>", "selectorsToggleClass": "active"}}'>
        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __($block->getBlockTitle()) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content my-account-sidebar <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>">
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <head>
        <title>My Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="sidebar.main.account_nav" template="Magento_Theme::html/collapsible.phtml" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_css" xsi:type="string">account-nav</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">nav items</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">250</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter" name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-1" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation-delimiter.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address Book</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/address</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">190</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</argument>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/edit</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">180</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Delimiter" name="customer-account-navigation-delimiter-2" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation-delimiter.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: we need more informations. can you show the layout?

Comment: For your info, I haven't touched the default layout. I just updated the template file which is vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html

Comment: I have put the default xml code at question